# Adverbial usage of "direct"

Tags: usage, registre

In conversation with a colleague, I just said:

> Rajoute à ça une formation parmi les meilleures sur le marché et tu auras une idée de ses compétences. Encore qu'aujourd'hui il m'a tout l’air d'une loque qu’a plus rien à voir avec ce qu’il a été. Quand je l’ai vu, ça m’a refroidi **direct**.

We were talking about how a certain ophthalmologist I used to look up to during a residency period now looks like a shadow of his former glorious self and how I suddenly became disillusioned.

1. I'm wondering if the adverbial "direct" in this particular sense  should be limited to informal use? If so, what words should I substitute in a more formal register?
2. In terms of phraseology, what other verbs than "refroidir" is the adverbial "direct"  commonly coupled with?

Answer (score 6):

Adverbial usage of ***direct*** is indeed informal. *Directement* is often the formal equivalent but here, *tout net* sounds better:

> *Quand je l’ai vu, ça m’a refroidi **tout net**.*

There are plenty of verbs that can be used with *direct*, e.g.:

> *Quand il m'a vu, il est **reparti direct**.*
>
> *Il est arrivé en retard et s'est **pris direct** un zéro.*
>
> *Dès que j'ai vu le gateau, je l'**ai mangé direct**.*
>
> ...

Another adverbial expression with a similar meaning is ***aussi sec***.

> *Il est reparti **aussi sec**.*

It is less informal than *direct*.

Comment: I don't think *aussi sec* is used as much nowadays. I'd even call it "formal" rather than "informal".

Comment: @TeleportingGoat According to the TLFi: *− Loc. adv., pop., fam. Aussi sec. Aussitôt, sans hésiter. Synon. du tac au tac.Un bout de conversation, et mon pouvoir séducteur opérera. − Et s'il n'opère pas? − Alors je vous saute dessus. Aussi sec (Queneau,Zazie,1959, p. 210).* I agree it is shifting from informal to mainstream/literary and a little outdated. I wouldn't say it is formal though.

Comment: What do you think of "*ça m’a refroidi **illico (presto)***" , "*je me suis couché **illico (presto)***" as one of the closest synonyms of "*direct*"?

Comment: *Illico* usage is raising according to Google books, but I don't hear it that much in everyday speech. It is probably moving toward the literary / formal side, like *sur-le-champ*.

Answer (score 0):

Je dirais que c'est un synonyme de "instantanément", avec une connotation un plus familière.

Je n'imagine pas trop un journaliste ou un politicien utiliser cette tournure pour commenter la journée d'hier (audition de William Barr) par exemple:

> Lorsque le Sénateur Kamala Harris exposa à quel point William Barr
>   avait pris sa décision d'abandonner toute charge contre Donald Trump
>   sans consulter le moindre élément du dossier Mueller, le public avisé
>   compris **direct** le double jeu du General Justice Attorney W. Barr.

Non dans ce cas, le journaliste utiliserait une autre tournure comme "instantanément".

Par contre, moi j'ai compris **direct**. Et c'est le ton et le terme que j'utiliserais en en parlant à une connaissance proche.

> Et t'as vu!? quand Ted Cruz s'est mis une encore énième fois à essayer de
>   re-re-re-diriger l'audition de William Barr à propos du dossier
>   Mueller, sur la piste abandonnée par James Comey des emails d'Hillary
>   Clinton volés par la Russie. J'ai compris **direct** que le parti
>   Républicain était totalement impliqué dans le fait de cacher la
>   vérité.

Voilà quelques exemples d'utilisation.

I have looked/listened at the "entire" audition. As a foreigner, a French: désolé d'être **direct** sur les faits: BARR DIDN'T EVEN READ THE MUELLER REPORT!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!